# function model() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, arguments, ode

I'm trying to estimate two parameter values `A` and `B` of an ODE using `curve_fit`, and then fit the solution to this ODE to my data set, plotting the results.

My code:

```
def model(I,t,A,B):
    dIdt = A*(2000 - I) + B*(2000 - I)*(I/2000)
    return dIdt

xData = # this is an np.array of my x values
yData = # this is an np.array of my y values
plt.plot(xData, yData, 'r.-', label='experimental-data')   #This part of the code seems to work

initialGuess = [1.0,1.0]    
popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, xData, yData, initialGuess)  #This is where the error is
print(popt)
xFit = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
I0 = 0
t = np.linspace(0,60)
I = odeint(model,I0,t)                                     #This is where i integrate the ODE to obtain I(t).

plt.plot(xFit, I(xFit, *popt), 'r', label='fit params: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The error I am getting is

`model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'B'.`

I roughly understand what's going on: my model() function takes in 4 arguments at the beginning: I,t,A and B. However, somewhere along the line, the code only recognizes these first 3 arguments, and leaves out B. I am not sure how to fix this.

I have tried a few things:

1. taking out the 'initialGuess' from the error line, so that there are 3 arguments in the `curve_fit` line , and this gave me a new error

`Improper input: N=3 must not exceed M=1`

which makes me think, that the initialGuess entry isn't the problem.

2. Changed `model` in the error line to `model()`, which gave me the error
   `model() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'I', 't', 'A', and 'B'`
3. Working off this, I changed `model` to `model(I,t,A,B)`, which ends up giving me `name 'A' is not defined`

And now I am lost.

All of these errors are happening in the same line, so I've tried changing things in there, but perhaps I am missing something else. Most of the online sources that touch on this error mention having to instantiate a class instance, but I'm unsure what this means in this context, I have not defined a class in the code.

I hope I've made my confusion clear, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you passing 't' into the definition of model? It doesn't get used, so there is no apparent need for it, and removing it would seem likely to fix your issue, though where you do your curve fit, you might want the initiaGuess before xData and yData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform curve_fit from scipy.optimize with `model` function (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def model(i, a, b):
    return a * (2_000 - i)\
           + b * (2_000 - i)\
           * (i / 2_000)


xData = np.array(range(10))
yData = model(xData, 1, 1)

initialGuess = [1.0, 1.0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f=model,
                       xdata=xData,
                       ydata=yData,
                       p0=initialGuess
                       )
print(popt)
```

Returns:

```
[1. 1.]
```

Next, Perform integration using `odeint` from `scipy.integrate`:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint

xFit = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
I0 = 0
t = np.linspace(0, 60)
a, b = 1, 1


def model(i, t, a, b):
    return a * (2_000 - i)\
           + b * (2_000 - i)\
           * (i / 2_000)


I = odeint(model, I0, t, args=(a, b))
plt.plot(xFit, I[:, 0], 'b', label= 'fit params: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Reveals the plot (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html):
[image]